# Android Share Intent Share Content Acknowledgement

Tags: android, android-intent, share

How to get acknowledgement that user share images or discard it after opening android share intent

Comment: Tell us what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: I need to know whether user discard or share the content after opening share intent it's a requirement of my app

Answer (score 0):

> How to get acknowledgement that user share images or discard it after opening android share intent ?

There is no way for it. You can not get status of it whether user has shared or discarded it.